# How do I improve performance when iterating through multiple conditions in R?

Tags: r, performance, iteration

Let's assume that I have a dataset with the following structure:

- I have N products
- I'm operating in N countries
- I have N payment partner
- May dataset contains of N days
- I have N different prices that customers can choose from

For example:

```
customer.id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
product <- c("product1","product2","product1","product2","product1","product2","product1","product2")
country <- c("country1","country2","country1","country2","country1","country2","country1","country2")
payment.partner <- c("pp1","pp2","pp1","pp2","pp1","pp2","pp1","pp2")
day <- c("day1","day2","day1","day2","day1","day2","day1","day2")
price <- c("price1","price2","price1","price2","price1","price2","price1","price2")

customer.data <- data.frame(customer.id,product,country,payment.partner,day,price)
customer.data <- data.table(customer.data)
```

Suppose I want to generate an aggregate out of it that, for instance, performs a forecasting algorithm for each combination. In order to do so, I identify the unique items for each condition and iterate it as follows:

```
unique.products <- droplevels(unique(customer.data[,product]))
unique.countries <- droplevels(unique(customer.data[,country]))
unique.payment.partners <- droplevels(unique(customer.data[,payment.partner]))
unique.days <- droplevels(unique(customer.data[,day]))
unique.prices <- droplevels(unique(customer.data[,price]))

for(i in seq_along(unique.products)){
  temp.data1 <- customer.data[product==unique.products[[i]]]
  for(j in seq_along(unique.countries)){
    temp.data2 <- temp.data1[country==unique.countries[[j]]]
    for(k in seq_along(unique.payment.partners)){
      temp.data3 <- temp.data2[payment.partner==unique.payment.partners[[k]]]
      for(l in seq_along(unique.days)){
        temp.data4 <- temp.data3[day==unique.days[[l]]]
        for(m in seq_along(unique.prices)){
          temp.data5 <- temp.data4[price==unique.prices[[m]]]
          if(nrow(temp.data5)!=0){
            # do your calculations here
            print(temp.data5)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In general, this code structure works fine, but it gets really annoying when applying real data with 5 million rows on it. I guess R is not the best language in terms of speed and performance. Of course, I have used multicore processing in the past or tried to get such an aggregate straight out of Hive or an MySQL DataWarehouse. Using another language like C++ or Python is also always an option.

However, sometimes all these options are not possible, which then always leads me to that exact same processing structure. So I'm wondering for quite a while if there is a better, respectively faster solution from a rather architectural point of view since it is known (and also becomes VERY clear when benchmarking) that for loops and frequent data subselection is very, very slow.

Grateful for all comments, hints and possible solutions!

Comment: I admit an interpreted language is slower than a compiled language, but I take offense from your claims of "almost general" knowledge. It's not the fault of the language if you don't know how to use it properly. You can write slow C++ code too.

Comment: i didn't mean to offend anyone. It's just that R is per se not designed to be super fast but rather to have a high usability and accessibility. See for instance Ben Webers Talk on his RServer project in which he tells that he sometimes has to justify for using R for data science applications: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGzTEuZvyK4

Comment: I couldn't agree more with @Roland. The general statements on the speed of the languages are just wrong. Unexperienced R users often conclude that it is slow because they apply 40+ year old C methods to solve their problems. R is a modern programming language and requires modern programming techniques to be efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I deleted "general knowledge" from my initial post. I guess I should be a bit more cautious with such subjective statements in the future.

Comment: And don't get me wrong: I really like working with R. It's just that I kept reading that it is slower than other languages. Since I won't stop using R, it is very good to know that this assumption seems to invalid.

Comment: @jd1338 R is listed regularly among top programming languages used by professionals in data science, a domain involving computations on massive datasets. It would not be so popular if it was inherently slow. The code makes the difference. A good introduction on the importance of writing efficient R code is given, e.g., in the book "Efficient R Programming" by Gillespie and Lovelace.

Comment: @jd1338 There are (rare) *specific tasks* that can be slow and are better done in other languages. Fortunately, it's easy to interface R with other languages, in particular with C++ via Rcpp.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments! I think I should have asked this question far earlier...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read the documentation of packages you are using. Package data.table offers some excellent [introductory tutorials](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html).

```
customer.data <- data.frame(customer.id,product,country,payment.partner,day,price)
library(data.table)
setDT(customer.data)
customer.data[, 
              print(customer.data[.I]), #don't do this, just refer to the columns you want to work on
              by = .(product, country, payment.partner, day, price)]
```

Of course, generally, you wouldn't print the data.table subset here, but work directly on specific columns.

Answer (score 2):

From your description (but not your code which I found incomprehensible as to its purpose, I am thinking you may want to use the `interaction function:

```
customer.data$grp=droplevels( with( customer.data,
              interaction(product, country ,payment.partner, day, price) ) )
 table(customer.data$grp)
#-----------------------
product1.country1.pp1.day1.price1 
                                4 
product2.country2.pp2.day2.price2 
                                4
```

You could then use `lapply( split( dat, dat$grp) , analytic_function)` to create separate analyses within subsets. I didn't have data.table loaded so showed the method for dataframes but there's no reason `interaction` shouldn't succeed in the `data.table` world:

```
customer.data[ , grp2 := droplevels(interaction( 
                                      product, country ,payment.partner, day, price) ) ]
```

Comment: but you don't need to create the `interaction` with data.table, since it offers (more) efficient grouping. Your solution is good within base R.

Comment: btw. `split` accepts a list of factors, so you wouldn't need to create the interaction yourself.

Comment: The data.table route is certainly more efficient and the syntax is reasonably intuitive once you learn to keep straight the differences between base and DT conventions.